# How do I return an array to child class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement a saving system from my game and I decided to do this by filling an array in the base class then return the whole array to an array from child class. But I keep getting an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'PlayerBodyPart[]' to 'PlayerBodyPart'. Can it be because child's array type is a struct?

```
public class LoadData : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerBodyPart LoadBPdata(string filePath, PlayerBodyPart[] bodyPart)
    {
        int id; int type; string name; int skill; string spritePath; int price; bool isUnlocked;

        int k = -1;

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {           
            if (lines[i].Contains("id"))
            {
                k += 1;
                id = Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(lines[i], @"\d+").Value);

                string typ = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 1], "type ", "");
              
                switch(typ)
                {
                    case ("Head"):
                        type = 0;
                        break;
                    case ("Body"):
                        type = 1;
                        break;
                    case ("Arms"):
                        type = 2;
                        break;
                    case ("Legs"):
                        type = 3;
                        break;
                    default:
                        type = 0;
                        break;
                }

                name = lines[i + 2];
                skill = Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(lines[i + 3], @"\d+").Value);
                spritePath = Application.dataPath + lines[i + 4];
                price = Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(lines[i + 5], @"\d+").Value);

                string unlockBool = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 6], "unlocked ", "");

                if (unlockBool == "True") isUnlocked = true;
                else isUnlocked = false;

                Debug.Log($"{id}, {type}, {name}, {skill}, {spritePath}, {price}, {isUnlocked}");
                
                bodyPart[k] = new PlayerBodyPart(id, type, name, skill, spritePath, price, isUnlocked);
            }          
        }
        return bodyPart;
    }
}
```

Child's code:

```
public struct PlayerBodyPart
{
    public enum PartType { Head, Body, Arms, Legs };

    public int id;
    public PartType type;
    public string name;
    public int skill;
    public Sprite sprite;
    public int price;
    public bool isUnlocked;

    public PlayerBodyPart(int id, int type, string name, int skill, string spritePath, int price, bool isUnlocked)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = (PartType)type;
        this.name = name;
        this.skill = skill;
        this.sprite = Resources.Load("spritePath") as Sprite;
        this.price = price;
        this.isUnlocked = isUnlocked;
    }
}

public class PlayerBPCatalogue : LoadData
{
    public PlayerBodyPart[] PBpart;

    public int n = 1000;

    public void Start()
    {
        PBpart = new PlayerBodyPart[n];
        string filePath = Application.dataPath + "/Data/bodyParts.txt";

        base.LoadBPdata(filePath, PBpart);           
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why are you using inheritance at all here? What is gained by making a class called "LoadData"? And I wouldn't make `PlayerBodyPart` a struct, because it contains way too much data to be efficient as a struct. Just make it a class and save yourself headaches.

Answer (score 0):

You should return an array, if you want to return an array. Change your return type to `PlayerBodyPart[]` and you are good to go.

```
public PlayerBodyPart[] LoadBPdata(string filePath, PlayerBodyPart[] bodyPart)
```

---

But I do think this is an xy-problem, because there are two problems here:

1. Passing an array will always be by reference, so passing it in and returning it makes no sense. You can just pass it in and you are good to go.
2. Instead of allocating an array with 1000 entries, why don't you use a [`List<PlayerBodyPart>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) instead? You don't need to return that either and you save yourself the hassle of allocating so much stuff.